# Ethernet driver missing when installing Windows using boot camp

Tags: windows, bootcamp, driver

I installed Windows 7 64 bit using bootcamp. The Ethernet driver is missing. Can't find it search on disk.  Where do I get this driver?

I have a Macbook Pro OS X

Answer (score 1):

Didn't read instructions. Using boot camp assistant, I need to select option to download Windows drivers and burn them on CD. Then boot into Windows and insert CD which will launch an installer for the drivers.